# I am using a bootstrap fixed header table now i want to set the scroll position when i am rendering to taht page

Tags: jquery, css

the fixed header is having below classes

```
<style>
    .table-fixed tbody
    {
        height: 580px;
        display: block;
        overflow-y: auto!important;
        border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
        position: relative;
        /*width: 100%;*/
    }

    .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody tr
    {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;

    }

    .table-fixed thead
    {
        width: calc(100%-1em);
        border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
    }

</style>
```

now I want to set the position of scroll bar on specific anchor tag

table like this 
      Part Numberabc1
aff-200abc2
abc 2 descabc 3 desc
a1000

Comment: share your full code

Comment: please make your question clear .

Comment: I have created one table with single column and that column has anchor tag list items in that and the table header is fixed. When ever I am selecting any anchor tag than scroll should also set to that position

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<table id="my_table">
    <tr id='row_1'><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_2'><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_3'><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_4'><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_5'><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_6'><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_7'><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_8'><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr id='row_9'><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

var container = $('div'),
scrollTo = $('#row_8');

container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + 
container.scrollTop()
});
```